# Code blocks Debugger failing to start

Tags: c++, c, windows, codeblocks

I am using a 64bit Windows OS and Code blocks version 17.12.
Whenever I try to debug my code, I get the following message and debug does not start.

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default  
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date  
Selecting target:  
Debug  
Adding source dir: C:\CX\will\  
Adding source dir: C:\CX\will\  
Adding file: C:\CX\will\bin\Debug\will.exe  
Changing directory to: C:/CX/will/.  
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Users\Vinay A\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Vinay A\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Users\Vinay A\AppData\Roaming\npm
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/CX/will/bin/Debug/will.exe  
failed
```

I have set the path in environment variables as `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`

I have also set the produce debugging flag `-g` in `CodeBlocks`.

The code is part of a console application project. 
The executable path for the debugger is `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`

What am I missing here?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the debugger exist at the path specified (i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`)?  Can you run the debugger via the cli?

Comment: Are you debugging C, C++ or mixed?  The C and C++ are distinct languages.  You should use `g++` for C++ and `gcc` (Yes, I know that the compiler will process correctly based on file extension).

Comment: Does `C:/CX/will/bin/Debug/will.exe` exist?

Comment: Are you running the 32 bit debugger to debug a 64 bit application?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Yes, gdb.exe is present in the specified location.

Comment: I uninstalled CodeBlocks version 17.12 and installed version 16.01. Now It's working.

Answer (score 2):

go to `Settings` and then `Debugger...` and `GDB/CDB debugger`
and press `Reset defaults`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install older version of code blocks since there is issue with the debugger for Code blocks version 17.12.